# Visual Studio 2010 form designer - groupbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, forms

Is it possible to limit the number of controls in a groupbox in VS 2010. I have a form where many groupboxes are visible or not depending on the code. That all works as it should. as I have been working on it in design view they are all over the place. Now it is ready to go I want them to be stacked (i.e.so when each groupbox is visible it is in the same plavce as the other controls that are not visible). when I stack them one groupbox becomes a control on the one below. Is there a way that I can make sure that doesn't happen. Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep it separates in design time, and set the position of the visible groupbox in runtime.

Other way could be transform each groupbox in a usercontrol, and load only the one you want to show. I prefer this one because keep the design clean. Put a panel in the place you want to show the groupbox, and work with the control collection of the pannel, clearing or adding user controls (the groupboxes) as needed.

Comment: Thankyou. I'm new to this and it can all get confusing.

Comment: :D no problem. Programming is a huge area of knowledge. I'm new in many things too.